# Angular - change route as if hitting address bar

Tags: angular

I want to navigate to `foobar.com/logout` page so that the logout function can be triggered.

I have tried doing this using the following pieces of code, which has not worked. Page navigates to `foobar.com/logout` page but it's not same as typing `foobar.com/logout` in the address bar and hitting enter where consequently logout function gets triggered.

```
this.router.navigate(['/logout']);

this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

When I use the above code, no request seems to be made to the backend application however, if I type `foobar.com/logout` in the address bar and hit enter, request is fired.

Routing module for the logout component is as follows;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LogoffComponent } from '@features/logoff/logoff/logoff.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'logout', component: LogoffComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LogoffRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: what address showed in your address bar when you using this `this.router.navigate(['/logout']);` or `this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout', { skipLocationChange: true });
`

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy Address bar shows foobar.com

Comment: I created sample stackblitz project. But it's working as expected. Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-tnzcde